# How to use a php variable value inside Html div

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a global php variable `$similarity;` and I have this Bootstrap progress bar by the following code:

```
<div class="progress progress-striped active">
<div class="bar" style="width: 74%;"></div> 
</div>
```

The width (74% in the case) determines the amount by which the progress bar will look filed.
What I want to do is to use the value of $similarity in place of that 74. So that progress bar will be filled according to the value of variable.

How can I do this?

Comment: Do you want the value to change as the user sits there staring at the screen, or do you want it to stay put at whatever value $similarity is when the user first requests the page?

Comment: if you wan to create multiple bar than you can use loop

Comment: Yes I want the the bar to be fixed when the user requests the page & gets whatever value is of $similarity. Th bar basically shows the similarity of two users entered by the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
<div class="progress progress-striped active">
<?php echo "<div class='bar' style='width: $similarity%;'></div>"; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you , it worked like charm ! 
How can I embed the above code inside my php tags. Since I want this progress bar to appear after the php has manipulated the value $similarity variable.

Comment: That would depend on how the rest of your PHP file looks, but this doesn't have to be in the same PHP tags as the part where you manipulate $similarity.  Something like this should work just fine:

<?php
$similarity = 35;
...
?>

<html>
...
<div class="progress progress-striped active">
<?php echo "<div class='bar' style='width: $similarity%;'></div>"; ?>
</div>
...
</html>

Answer (score 10):

you can do this by

```
<div class="bar" style="width: <?php echo $similarity; ?>%;">
```

but make sure file extension is **.php**